# How to implement text input hierarchy similar to iCloud Sign In at standard Settings app in tvOS?

Tags: tvos

I need to implement a login UI in my tvOS application, but I don't want to use `UIAlertController` for the text input. Instead of this I want to implement a text input UI similar to the iCloud Sign In in the Settings app without any additional `UITextFields`.

[image: tvOS iCloud Sign In]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a table view populated with some cells with embedded text fields.

These UITextField than becomes input responder like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        // my UITableViewCell extended with UITextField 
        TextFieldCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. place text field on a view (If you dont wont to show it, place it out of borders)
2. in viewController code add `inputAccesoryView` method
3. When you need to show your input view - call `[self.loginTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

I found that input accesory view located in top right corner of standart input view, so code for it should look like this:

```
-(UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    if (!inputAccessoryView) {
        CGRect accessFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1920, 200);
        inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:accessFrame];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-500, -100, 1000, 100)];
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:59];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        titleLabel.text = @"Login";
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [inputAccessoryView addSubview:titleLabel];

         descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-500, 0, 1000, 100)];
         descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:29];
         descriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         descriptionLabel.text = @"Enter your E-mail or Login";
         descriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [inputAccessoryView addSubview:descriptionLabel];  
    }
    return inputAccessoryView;
}
```

It work for me.